# Cannot See Files in Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14 LTS Server

Tags: windows-7, files, home-directory

I am totally new to setting up a home server, Ubuntu and Linux programming.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server and I can see the Ubuntu server under networks in Windows 7, but I cannot see any files when I go to the file browser. I have noticed during the boot process that `smb/cifs file and active directory` is failing to boot.

I have reinstalled the software several times hoping that it would correct itself but it did not. I have scoured the wikis and read many forums trying to solve the issue myself. Can someone guide me in the right direction please..?

Comment: share files between your Linux Server and your Windows machine, you can use Samba. See this guide How to Create a Network Share Via Samba Via CLI on how to set it up on your Ubuntu Server

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to edit cnd,conf in samba but I could not. It looks like nano is installed for editing and I tried to edit the file did a write and save with your suggestions rebooted and still no access. This is real frustrating. I have been at this for 3 days..

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ubuntu and GNU/Linux!

As things stand, Windows won't be able to do anything with your Ubuntu Server files on a number of levels:

1) It won't be able to log into the system. (You would need to use ssh for this) See: [SSH on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/ConnectingTo). This won't help you with file transfers directly, but it will  help to manage your server from Windows.

2) It won't by default be able to read the Linux filesystem. (I'm presuming your server has the default ext4 filesystem).

To share files between your Linux Server and your Windows machine, you can use Samba. See this guide [How to Create a Network Share Via Samba Via CLI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!) on how to set it up on your Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your help I tried your instructions but it did no work. What worked for me was the instructions from Liberian Geek on "[Ubuntu Tips - Create Samba File Server in Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/07/ubuntu-tips-create-samba-file-server-ubuntu-14-04/)" I followed the instruction to the T and it worked.

Again Thanks for your help...

Comment: I'm sorry my suggestion didn't work for you, but I'm glad you found a solution. Please could you edit this answer to include a link to the tutorial that you found more useful, and maybe the key points that helped you. That way other people can benefit from your experience. Askubuntu is mostly "staffed" by amateur enthusiasts like you and me.